# Terraform, select value from powershell gridview

Tags: powershell, terraform

I have executed a terraform file that makes a call to powershell commands. My idea is that the different subscriptions appear on the screen and select one of them so that later I can create certain resources in Azure.

After the selection, the Resource Group is created correctly in the selected subscription, but after executing it again, and selecting another subscription, I do not create anything else and the add and delete message appears

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "=1.28.0"
 }

resource "null_resource" "script1" {

    triggers {
        build_number = "${timestamp()}"
    }
    provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
        Login-AzureRmAccount
        $SubscriptionId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | select Name, State, SubscriptionId, TenantId | Out-GridView -Title "Azure Subscription Selector" -PassThru).SubscriptionId
        Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId | Select-AzureRmSubscription
    EOT

        interpreter = ["powershell"]
        }
    }

#variable "subscripcion" {}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resources_groups" {
    name        =  "resources_groups"
    location    =   "west europe"
 }
```

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 1 destroyed.

How could I use this option and could I use a different subscription to create the indicated resources without deleting what I have already implemented?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you do the terraform apply it first refreshes the state of the existing resources. Let's say you've created the resource group in one subscription already, when you run apply again, it's going to refresh the state of the resource group in that particular subscription.

When you confirm the apply operation, it will change the subscription selected in your local shell (via the null_resource) but at this point it has already calculated that no changes are required in the previously selected subscription.

If you were to run this again once the local-exec has selected the desired subscription, it would probably work.

May I suggest that you pass the subscription_id as an argument when you call terraform apply? This way the provider would be configured with the correct subscription from the beginning.

Code below:

```
variable "subscription_id" {
  type = "string"
}

provider "azurerm" {
    version = "=1.28.0"
    subscription_id = var.subscription_id
 }

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resources_groups" {
    name        =  "resources_groups"
    location    =   "uksouth"
 }
```

and call using the command `terraform apply -var 'subscription_id=<my_subscription_id>`

You could then just run terraform using powershell to have the interactive selection

```
Login-AzAccount
$SubscriptionId = (Get-AzSubscription | select Name, State, SubscriptionId, TenantId | Out-GridView -Title "Azure Subscription Selector" -PassThru).SubscriptionId
terraform apply -var `subscription_id=$SubscriptionId`
```

Comment: First, forgive the delay in answering. Thank you very much for your indications. They have worked for me correctly!